# VWD problem: Treats the compiled DLL of the project as duplicated assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

After I recompile my project it generates a gazillion erros of the following:

```
Warning CS0436
The type 'AAA.Data.Report' in 'E:\Projects\AAA\AAA\Data\Entities.Designer.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'AAA.Data.Report' in 'e:\Projects\AAA\AAA\bin\Rlp.dll'. Using the type defined in 'E:\Projects\AAA\AAA\Data\Entities.Designer.cs'.
File: E:\Projects\AAA\AAA\Data\Entities.Designer.cs
Line: 16
Column: 306
Project: AAA


Error CS0121
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AAA.Components.Functions.TriggerButtonClickOnReturn(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)' and 'AAA.Components.Functions.TriggerButtonClickOnReturn(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)'
File: E:\Projects\AAA\AAA\Pages\Search.aspx.cs
Line: 17
Column: 17
Project: AAA
```

And the project doesn't compile till I delete the file AAA.dll (the project's assembly).
This is really frustrating, if anyone encountered such an error before please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did (as a workaround) and works for me, is I created a console app that manually deletes the dll of the website right before the building.

I call it in the build events of the website.